# Free datasets of Europe's historical country borders since the Middle Ages

Tags: data, borders, history

Is there a source for historical shapefiles of Europe since the Middle Ages?

There was a promising answer to the similar question 
[Is there a source for historical shapefiles of Europe in the modern era?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75656/is-there-a-source-for-historical-shapefiles-of-europe-in-the-modern-era)
but the link provided doesn't work (anymore).